How to install Thunderbird 128 "Nebula" from the PPA?
I added the repository ppa:mozillateam/ppa, but it installs the Thunderbird 115 instead of the latest 128.
Is there any way to install Thunderbird 128 from a PPA?
Alternatively is there any deb version available of Thunderbird 128?
I'm not interested in flatpaks, snaps or manually updated packages.

have you tried asking your question on Mozilla Support/Thunderbird? I've always found them very responsive.

@graham Good idea, I will do that.

you may also be interested in reading this It's FOSS post

You can install it by downloading the .tar.bz2 file

@kyodake That would mean no updates, right? I don't want that...

@Ap0st0l: Whenever an update is available, Thunderbird will notify you and you can install it manually. I've been doing this for years with LibreOffice, Firefox and Thunderbird.

@Ap0st0l what about installing it directly from snap?

Ok, I gathered some information myself and I'm ready to share!
For now there is only version 115 on the stable PPA ppa:mozillateam/ppa.
No one knows when it will be updated, but it will be in the future. This is a stable, well-tested version, that's why it is still recommended to use.
Stable repository: https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
There is also the beta PPA ppa:mozillateam/thunderbird-next.
Although there is only version 125, no 128 "Nebula". It will for sure be updated quicker than stable PPA. It has slightly newer UI than 115, so it's worth checking. From the other side it can contain bugs (the same goes for 128), so it shouldn't be used on production.
Beta repository: https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/thunderbird-next
To use the beta PPA you can remove firstly the stable PPA (if you have it) and install the beta:
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:mozillateam/ppa
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/thunderbird-next
sudo apt update
sudo apt install thunderbird

Possibly just sudo apt upgrade could upgrade the Thunderbird to beta, without removing old PPA, but I didn't check it.
Also if you want to keep both repositories, you can force installing the chosen beta version of Thunderbird like so:
sudo apt install thunderbird=1:125.0+build3-0ubuntu0.24.04.1~mt1

tl;dr There is no version 128 available as a PPA or deb, but you can use version 125 from the beta PPA repository and wait there for 128.


Thunderbird version 128.0 is only offered as direct download from thunderbird.net and not as an upgrade from Thunderbird version 115 or earlier. A future release will provide updates from earlier versions.

(via the official site)
You can install the tar file by clicking "Download" in the hyperlink I provided above

The problem is that the user requires a .deb file, not a .tar.bz2 file. Is there any deb version available for Thunderbird 128?   I don't want that...

I'm not interested in manually updated packages.
